# dynamically call method of a child class in java

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, parent-child

i want to use the method of my child class dynamically!
      how can i access to child method?
      the parent class is :

```
public abstract class A{
    String temp;
    public abstract String getData();

    public void setData(String temp){
         this.temp=temp;
}
```

and childs class is:

```
 public class B extends A{

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return "B--GetData";
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(String temp) {
        this.temp= temp+"-B";
    }
```

---

```
    public class C extends A{

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return "C--GetData";
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(String temp) {
        this.temp= temp+"-C";

    }
 }
```

i use this code to access my child class

```
String parseData(String Name){
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(Name);
    cls.getMethods();
}
```

how  can i able to call for example getData() method from class C dynamically?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String parseData(String Name) throws Exception {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(Name);
    Method[] methods = cls.getMethods();

    for (Method method : methods) {
        if(method.getName().equals("setData")) {
            method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), "Test");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please try to use like that.

You call method like below

```
parseData(C.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your method like this :

```
methods[0].invoke(new B(), null); 
you can use `method[1]` or `new C()` based on which method to call and on which object.
```

The below code *also* shows how to access *private* methods as well.
Example :

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

class ExitPuzzle extends MyAbstractClass {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class clazz = MyAbstractClass.class;
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(methods));
        methods[0].setAccessible(true); // needed only if method is non-public
        methods[0].invoke(new ExitPuzzle(), null);
    }

}

abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    private void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("in MyAbstractClass");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, If I'm understanding you correctly ? for  method[0]  i needs to make a array of method name?
   but i dont want to use new B() , i want do all steps dynamically, then if a Name be instanse of C or B then its work true!

Comment: @SDWACW - You need to tell - *On which object you want to call the method*, right?. `new B()` or `new C()` or `yourInstance` does that.

Comment: thanks , but i don't know , its definition run time ; i override toString method for both child class and if i use "System.out.println(cls.newInstance().toString());"it can recognize true child, how i do same thing with my method? is it possible?